# Ruby Array of Arrays returning query to be used for chartjs,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def self.return_this_data_for_map_method
    data = { :labels => [], datasets: [data: []] }
    dictionary = {}
    results.each do |teams|
        team = teams[0]
        teamMembers = teams[1]

        if dictionary[team].nil?
            dictionary[team] = teamMembers
        else 
            dictionary[team] += teamMembers

        end
    end
    data[:labels] << dictionary.keys
    data[:datasets][0][:data] << dictionary.values
    data
end
```

This is the data I am getting out

```
 => {:labels=>[["CUBS", "CARDS", "ROCKIES", "ASTROS"]]:datasets=>[{:data=>[[72, 93, 74, 28]]}]}
```

This is how I am trying to get my data

```
=> {:labels=>["CUBS", "CARDS", "ROCKIES", "ASTROS"], :datasets=>[{:data=>[72, 93, 74, 28]}]}
```

It's wrapping it like it's still in an Array of Arrays, I am not quite seeing how to break how of it.  Any suggestions on how I can fix my code would be appreciated.

using ruby 2.3.1

Comment: have you try with `data[:labels] += dictionary.keys` or `data[:labels] = dictionary.keys` ?

Comment: You mean instead of shoveling it?

Comment: you should either use `+=` or `concat`. `<<` is used to push a single value only (in this case the 'single value' is an array). Preferably `+=`, since it doesn't mutate the array like `push`, `concat`, or `<<` do.

Comment: Can you show the structure and data in results?

Comment: I don't have the structure at the moment, the data is basically like this 
    [['cubs', 1]['cubs', 1]['cubs', 1]['cubs', 1]['cubs', 1]['astros', 1]['astros', 1]['astros', 1]]

Comment: @maxpleaner - i will look into that in the morning.

Comment: Would be helpful to have a concrete example of an input value and its expected output.

Comment: @maxpleaner -- Thank you problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to flatten the arrays prior to returning the data:

```
data = { :labels => [], datasets: [data: []] }
dictionary = {}
results.each do |teams|
    team = teams[0]
    teamMembers = teams[1]

    if dictionary[team].nil?
        dictionary[team] = teamMembers
    else 
        dictionary[team] += teamMembers

    end
end
data[:labels] << dictionary.keys
data[:datasets][0][:data] << dictionary.values
data[:labels].flatten!
data[:datasets][0][:data].flatten!
data
```

Answer (score 0):

@maxpleaner and @rails_id were correct

```
def self.return_this_data_for_map_method
data = { :labels => [], datasets: [data: []] }
dictionary = {}
results.each do |teams|
    team = teams[0]
    teamMembers = teams[1]

    if dictionary[team].nil?
        dictionary[team] = teamMembers
    else 
        dictionary[team] += teamMembers

    end
end
data[:labels] += dictionary.keys
data[:datasets][0][:data] += dictionary.values
data
```

end